# Does GCH for alephs imply the axiom of choice?

Tags: set-theory, axiom-of-choice, continuum-hypothesis, gch

GCH for alephs means the statement that, for any aleph $\kappa$, there are no cardinals $\mathfrak{r}$ such that $\kappa<\mathfrak{r}<2^\kappa$.

Does GCH for alephs imply the axiom of choice?

Remark. Lindenbaum and Tarski assert in ``Communication sur les recherches de la théorie des ensembles'' without proof that GCH for alephs is equivalent to Cantor's aleph hypothesis that $2^{\aleph_\alpha}=\aleph_{\alpha+1}$ for all ordinals $\alpha$ (see page 188, No. 96). But as we know (although Lindenbaum and Tarski possibly do not kown) Cantor's aleph hypothesis implies AC. This means that Lindenbaum and Tarski in fact also assert that GCH for alephs implies the axiom of choice. But I do not see how to prove it.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The answer is positive, yes.

Note that $2^\kappa\leq 2^{\kappa^+}$, and therefore $\kappa^+\leq\kappa^++2^\kappa\leq 2^{\kappa^+}$. So either $2^\kappa=2^{\kappa^+}$ or $2^\kappa=\kappa^+$.

In the first case $\kappa^+$, $\kappa<\kappa^+<2^\kappa$ is impossible. So the latter case holds.

Therefore the power set of an ordinal can be well-ordered, and the Axiom of Choice follows in $\sf ZF$.

Comment: How do you deduce $2^k=2^{k^+}$ from $k^++2^k=2^{k^+}$?

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/a/30339/622

Comment: I believe this argument appears in Levi's "Basic Set Theory" and there are some historical remarks too.

Comment: @PaceNielsen: Thanks! I've never really looked through Levy's book. I just know that Matti Rubin used to love it because it was very formal and thorough (which may have influenced the lack of interest to open it for a read), and that Azriel said he wrote it in Plain$\rm\TeX$... But I'll look it up.

Comment: @Pace: I could find Specker's theorem that GCH implies AC, not GCH for $\aleph$s. Do you have a specific reference? (He uses $\frak a^+$ to denote the Hartogs number of $\frak a$, which coincides in the case where $\frak a$ is an $\aleph$.)

Comment: @PaceNielsen I also like Azriel's book very very much. There is only the proof of GCH${}\Rightarrow{}$AC in that book, although the proof given by Asaf is similar to that proof.

Comment: @GuozhenShen That's all I meant: the proof argument is similar.